# Refer vs. specify vs. mention

Tags: word-choice

I have a technical document which is a set of rules of how to write the CSS code.

One of the rules is about describing HEX colors in a "human-readable" way.

> Refer to the name of [edit: the] color in the comment.
>
> ```
> .some_element         { color: #ff0000 }  /* #ff0000 is red */
> .some_another_element { color: #00ff00 }  /* #00ff00 is green */
> ```

Is the word "refer" the best option here? Or maybe I should change it to something like "specify" or "mention"?

Comment: Any of them looks fine to me. I would write _the name of the color_ but US English may differ about the second _the_.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks :-) The omission of the second "the" in my example was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the three you suggest would convey the meaning clearly. You could also use *state*, *give*, *include* and probably many more which I cannot think of at the moment.